# burning ubuntu to disc

Tags: iso, burning

I have tried burning Ubuntu 12.04 to disc by using `Nero` and also using `infrarecorder`.

When i use `infrarecorder` and burn as image and check files on disc, I only get four files and not the reset.

I have seen in how to burn in Ubuntu help, that I am not getting the full operating system to burn.

I am not sure if this is down to my equipment, or down to iso file itself.

At present I'm using Windows xp, and worried if I continue after April 8th I will start to run in to problems.

I just need to burn Ubuntu iso file properly so I can use it as a dual boot up.

Comment: If you have a spare USB flash drive, the easiest option is to use unetbootin to make a bootable usb. http://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Bootable-Ubuntu-with-USB-Drive-Using-UNetbootin

Comment: have you checked the size of the iso you have downloaded? you might have an incomplete iso. Re-download it. Mount it with Daemon tools and check the files. All these files should be written to your DVD.